# Is it possible to assign const values through itertation

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, constants

I am creating an application where the list of inputs will be created and rendered at runtime. Based on the service calls, the application will generate the forms dynamically.

I am using material design framework for text fields and I need to instantiate the MDCTextField. For that, i need to create constants as

`const textField1 = new MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field__input_FirstName'))`;

As I need to render around 5 fields, I need to create 5 const at runtime. Is there anyway to create constants via iteration?

```
const textField1 = new MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field__input_FirstName'));
const textField2 = new MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field__input_LastName'));
const textField3 = new MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field__input_Address'));
const textField4 = new MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field__input_City'));
const textField5 = new MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field__input_State'));
```

**Note**: If users don't like this question, please don't mark it as an ineligible question. Since I need a proper way to resolve.

Comment: what programming language is this? please tag your question properly

Comment: Could you create a `const` object and assign these text fields to it? The `const` keyword in ES6 doesn't mean an object is immutable, so I'm not sure you will gain much from this...

Comment: Why would you need to create separate variables like this? Why not make an array of them all instead?